# Xpath is not working for the following button

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Following  is the `xpath` which is not working:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[10]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/button")).click();
```

The [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YenWr.jpg) shows the button which is not working

Comment: Provide the HTML code please.

Comment: what exception you get ? (always catch the exception to know more information about the reason.)

Comment: please install xpath checker and test it before you using any code

Comment: It is completely unclear what you mean by "not working" and you have withheld an important piece of information - the HTML document you are querying. Voting to close. @ran No need to remind everyone to use an XPath checker - most people already have an XPath plugin - that's the reason why the ask here.

Comment: sorry but i use css selector

Answer (score 0):

Why not Try CSS Selectors.

```
driver.findElement(By.CssSelector(".btn"));
```

Comment: If you are only looking at using XPATH. please share the exception that you have come across while running the script

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
//div[@class='text-right btns imme_result_btns']/button[@type='button']
```

If it didn't work then please share your HTML code in question so we can help you better

Hope it will help you :)

get back to me if still facing any issue :)